# Find the difference between 2 dates in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to use Python to work out the difference between 2 dates.

Currently my code is as follows

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.form['name']       #Pulls name from html form
    rawstartdate = request.form['date1']   #Pulls First date from html form
    rawenddate = request.form['date2']    #Pulls End date from html form
    datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(rawstartdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    startdate1 = datetimeobject.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')   #Change First date to UK format
    datetimeobject2 = datetime.strptime(rawenddate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    enddate1 = datetimeobject2.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')   #Change End date to UK format
    a = datetime.strptime(startdate1, date_format)
    b = datetime.strptime(enddate1, date_format)
    delta = b - a
    duration=(delta.days) #Calculate difference in days between Variables
    print(duration) # for debugging
    record = database(user=name,startdate=startdate1,enddate=enddate1,duration=duration)
```

In the code, I fetch the Dates from the Datepicker from the front end website. This is by default passed to Python in Year-Month-Date. I convert this to the standard UK date format before inserting into my database for storage.

The issue i am having is the datatime function of ".days" is returning an incorrect value.

For example if the dates are "20-10-2021" To "21-10-2021". The program is returning "1" I am expecting the program to return "2" as there are 2 days between the dates "20th" and "21st".

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not two days between the 20th and the 21st. If the 20th is Wednesday and the 21st is Thursday they are one day apart. Sounds like you want inclusive but then you'll probably run into a corner case around midnight. Look up the "fence post problem", aka [Off by One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Also `21 - 20 = 1`.

Also, you are doing way too much date munging. You don't need to convert to *UK format* once you have a `datetime` object you can *display* it in whatever format you want. Please don't be storing dates as strings in your database. If you're using an ORM the database will store it however it wants, it's up to you to choose how to display it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take this into account. I was under the incorrect understanding that even after changing the values to UK format the database was storing them as Integer where as it seems it is as a string

Comment: The database probably is storing as an integer, aka a timestamp. You shouldn't worry about the internal workings of the db, all you care about is getting a `datetime` object and then displaying in your desired format. ps. it's common courtesy to upvote helpful answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the program returns the correct value.

If your expected result is always one added with the result, I suggest you may add 1 with the result.